# presto sql query for getting the fill rate of the table

Tags: sql, bigdata, presto, trino, sal

I want a generic query to get  fill rate of all columns in table .Query should work irrespective of the column number.I have to implement this using presto sql.I have tried searching for a method but nothing seems to working.

**Input**

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | null | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| Null | Null | Null | 5 |

Output

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.66 | 0.33 | 0.33 | 1.0 |

Explanation:
A Col contains 3 rows with 2 non null values so 2/3
B and C Cols contain 2 null value and one non null value so 1/3
D col there is no null values so 3/3

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please share the sample data and desired output.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the reply,I have added the required details

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Presto/Trino does not provide dynamic query execution capabilities (i.e. something like EXEC in T-SQL) so the only option (unless you are ready to go down [user defined function](https://trino.io/docs/current/develop/functions.html) road) to write a query which will enumerate all needed columns (if you are using client from another language - you can build the query dynamically leveraging `information_schema.columns` info):

```sql
with dataset(A, B, C, D) as (
    values (1, null, null, 1),
        (2, 2, 3, 4),
        (Null, Null, Null, 5)
)

select 1.00 * count_if(a is not null) / count(*) a,
    1.00 * count_if(b is not null) / count(*) b,
    1.00 * count_if(c is not null) / count(*) c,
    1.00 * count_if(d is not null) / count(*) d
from dataset;
```

Output:

| a | b | c | d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.67 | 0.33 | 0.33 | 1.00 |

Comment: Hi, Thanks again,Is there any way to loop through the column we get from information schema ?

Comment: @aju_dev AFAIK Presto does not have PL/SQL like capabilities so you will need either to execute one query which will generate another one using information_schema and then manually execute the generated query or use some external client scripting to fully automate it.